# Using Entity Framework to insert row to a table that has a composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am inserting a new row to the database table using Entity Framework, but my problem is that column `ValidFromDate` is causing an exception

> The property 'ValidFromDate' is part of the object's key information
>   and cannot be modified date

Our DBA has defined database and image below is the snapshot of the EDMX file. `ValidFromDate` is a *datetime* column.

Idea of the `FarmAnimal` is to track the history of where certain animal has been. Therefore `AnimalId` **and** `ValidFromDate` causes the row to be unique.

Now the question is that how can I can insert new row to the table that has this kind of schema?

[image: EDMX]

Insert using Entity Framework

```
var farmAnimal = new FarmAnimal {
   AnimalId = insert.AnimalId,
   ValidFromDate = insert.ValidFromDate // exception comes from this line,
   etc.
};
entities.FarmAnimals.Add(farmAnimal);
```

**Update: StackTrace**

```
   at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperties(Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInScalarAndComplexProperties(IList`1 entries)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at xxx.Repositories.PairingRepository.UpdateFarmAnimals(IEnumerable`1 updates, IEnumerable`1 inserts) in xxx
   at xxx.Services.PairingService.RemovePairingAnimals(List`1 animalIds) in xxx
   at xxx.Controllers.PairingController.RemovePairingAnimals(List`1 animalIds) in xxx
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

**Update 2: Entity Framework files**

I have added three files Entity Framework mapping files / generators 
EDMX file
ADO.NET DbContext Generator 
ADO.NET EntityObject Generator (POCO's)

Comment: At which point does the exception occur? One of the setters, the ObjectSet.Add method, when you save changes? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @cynic See comment on the source code block. I will get the stack trace now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I see that you're using the DbSet/DbContext wrapper layer. Are the entities POCOs, or are they generated with all the change tracking logic?

Comment: Also, I take it the call fails when there is at least a single FarmAnimal already present in the in-memory context (FarmAnimals.Local)?

Comment: @cynic I assume that my .tt file is not "ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator" because generated .cs files seems to contain only POCOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DbSet wrapper fails before it even does anything with your new FarmAnimal - DetectChanges is called before AddObject on the underlying ObjectContext, and it somehow detects forbidden changes in a FarmAnimal already loaded/added to the context. If you're using POCOs with proxies or just plain boring classes generated with change tracking (that's NOT the same as "Self-Tracking Entities", just the classes that get generated when you add a new data model with vanilla VS2010), you can [turn off automatic detection of changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/06/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-12-automatically-detecting-changes.aspx) so that it does not get called.

Comment: I made first tests on your solution. It seems to work, I'll just test little bit more and then mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Works smoothly after doing similar settings like in the provided link (chapter "Disabling automatic detection of changes"). After 20 hours I can award bounty. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it doesn't crash earlier, seeing as AnimalId and ValidFromDate are both PrimaryKeys, AnimalId imo should never be set in your code but should be a automatic counter.

after searching "The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified date" I got this hit: http://forums.asp.net/t/1747622.aspx/1

which probably will explain it better then I ever will

Comment: Remember that this is not Animal table, so AnimalId itself is not unique, but combination of AnimalId and ValidFromDate. In the Animal table there is automatic counter for AnimalId.

Comment: I still don't understand why they both are PrimaryKeys. My guess is that EF doesn't allow you to set a DateTime as a primarykey because it can never be sure of the fact that it's unique.